# I can't load game with my google account!

Tags: pokemon-go

Yesterday my game was reset and when I tried to load again it does not let me load with google.
When It says sign in with google and you click there the Pokéball keeps spinning over and over and never ends!!

I saw a related question on Arqade, but the answer didn't help me: on my mobile When I go to settings then account and google there is no sign in and security option.

Comment: dont shout and keep calm. try later to check if is a server connection error ...

Answer (score 0):

It is just a server issue (most probably) sometimes people can log in but all the gyms/stops and nearby Pokemon still won't load when it displays the map. So try again later, if you keep these problems i suggest:

open the Pokemon go app -> click on the red and white pokeball to open the menu -> click on settings.
In settings look for sign out (it's on the bottom) then you will be logged out and can log back in with your google account.

Usually if you experience a reset it means you logged in with an other account (or the server couldn't be reached resulting in the previously described scenario)